# Application Roles in SQL Server and guest account for cross database query?

Tags: sql-server

From MSDN: [Application Roles on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190998.aspx)

> An application role is a database principal that enables an application to run with its own, user-like permissions. You can use application roles to enable access to specific data to only those users who connect through a particular application. Unlike database roles, application roles contain no members and are inactive by default. Application roles work with both authentication modes. Application roles are enabled by using sp_setapprole, which requires a password. Because application roles are a database-level principal, they can access other databases only through permissions granted in those databases to guest. Therefore, any database in which guest has been disabled will be inaccessible to application roles in other databases.

Can someone explain this to me?

Does this mean that I cannot write a cross database query which refers to tables from another database on the same SQL Server Instance if guest account is disabled for that instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, disabling the guest account on an instance is IMHO a bad idea. The guest account is designed to allow users to "see" databases (and very little more). Disabling the guest account for the instance (and consequestially master) will stop enumeration of the databases which may well stop an otherwise authenticated role connecting, depending on the connection string used. You can grant an application role to one or more databases and instances and the application running under this account will have access (unless its denied in some other way) Thus any userrs who can run the applicaion will have that access via the application) Its a way of allowing an application t do something without granting the user those rights.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905195%28v=sql.80%29.aspx By Instance I presume you mean sQL install instance...?